# Sorting query in two columns with validation value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like this:

```
===================
id | name    | year
1  | Andy    | 1993
2  | Carroll | 1987
3  | Steve   | -973
4  | John    | null
===================
```

How I can sort the data to:

```
===================
id | name    | year
3  | Steve   | -973
4  | John    | null
2  | Carroll | 1987
1  | Andy    | 1993
===================
```

Comment: `ORDER BY name DESC`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner nice thinking outside the box! :)

Answer (score 3):

If `year` is not integer type, apply `cast` and `coalesce`:

```
select *
from yourtable
order by cast(coalesce(year,0) as int)
```

If it is an integer, `coalesce` alone is sufficient:

```
select *
from yourtable
order by coalesce(year,0)
```

This will treat `null` value in year column as `0`

---

Why the difference? Numbers as text sort differently than numbers, and here you want to sort numbers.

Comment: its work but i want to sort the valid year in the first how the query?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If it's working then what else is not? Could you explain? If you need the reverse order apply `order by ... DESC` keyword at the end

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to treat `year` as `0` when it is `NULL`.  If that is the logic:

```
order by coalesce(year, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the comment about wanting to sort valid years first, you can change the query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY (COALESCE(year,-1) >= 0) DESC, COALESCE(year,0)
```

Output:

```
id  name        year
2   Carroll     1987
1   Andy        1993
3   Steve       -973
4   John        (null)
```

`COALESCE(year,-1) >= 0` will return 1 for year >= 0 and 0 otherwise, so "valid" years (year >= 0) will sort first in the list.

**Edit**

To sort (null) years before invalid ones, change the `ORDER BY` to

```
ORDER BY (COALESCE(year,-1) >= 0) DESC, COALESCE(year,-2147483648)
```

This will ensure (null) values are lower than any year values and thus will sort before them.

Output:

```
id  name        year
2   Carroll     1987
1   Andy        1993
4   John        (null)
3   Steve       -973
```

Comment: thankyou very much. one more question, how if i want  to sort valid years,null and then invalid years?

Comment: and can i order by name ascending?

Comment: Do you mean order by name if the same year?

Comment: If so just add `, name` to the end of the `ORDER BY`

Comment: order by name in the same valid year,null year and invalid year. so with your last edit the result will be : Andy,Carroll,john and steve

Comment: If the year has to be the same to sort by name, just adding name to the end of the `ORDER BY` will work. If you don't care about the year but just want to sort by name after deciding if the year is valid or not, change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY SIGN(COALESCE(year,  0)) DESC, name`

Comment: Okay, Thank you very very very much :D